# What's the difference between EnableEurekaClient and EnableDiscoveryClient?

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

In some applications, I saw people are using `@EnableEurekaClient`. And some other example applications are using `@EnableDiscoveryClient`.

Is there any difference between these two?

Answer (score 238, accepted):

There are multiple implementations of "Discovery Service" (eureka, [consul](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-consul), [zookeeper](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-zookeeper)).  `@EnableDiscoveryClient` lives in [spring-cloud-commons](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons) and picks the implementation on the classpath.  `@EnableEurekaClient` lives in [spring-cloud-netflix](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/) and only works for eureka.  If eureka is on your classpath, they are effectively the same.

Comment: Question : Will both of above mentioned annotations enable Ribbon-enabled interceptor injected into RestTemplate? Any difference in behavior? I noticed that in previous Spring Cloud implementations `@LoadBalanced` was automatically applied, but in current version, it is required explicitly. Thank you.

Comment: Yes. There is no difference. The load balanced annotation has been required for a long time.

Comment: Why would someone want to use @EnableEurekaClient over the more general @EnableDisocveryClient?  Wouldn't that bind them to the eureka implementation and make it harder to switch SD backends in the future?

Comment: Yes. The only answer is if they want to be clear and enforce eureka.

Answer (score 7):

Discovery service concept in spring cloud is implemented in different ways like Eureka, consul, zookeeper etc. If you are using Eureka by Netflix then @EnableEurekaClient is specifically for that. But if you are using any other service discovery including Eureka you can use @EnableDiscoveryClient.

Comment: perfect explaination

Answer (score 3):

In terms of its practicality and simplicity, if the registered center is eureka, then `@EnableEurekaClient` is recommended. If it is another registration center, `@EnableDiscoveryClient` is recommended.

Answer (score 3):

@EnableEurekaCient will initilize the service discovery using eureka server, its like explicitly specifying to use EUREKA

While @EnableDiscovery Client will register dicovery service using the jar available in classpath like consul, Eureka, Kubernetes.

Answer (score 1):

@EnableEurekaClient works only for Eureka if we use @EnableDiscoveryClient we can use any discovery client like Consul other than Eureka